# Salesforce App Custom Fields on Standard Objects

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I'm trying to distribute an app that requires a few custom fields on the standard Lead object. Creating the custom fields was straightforward for my organization, I simply added them under My Name->Setup->Customize. What I'm trying to figure out is how to insure that people installing my app also have these custom fields available. If someone could outline the steps required to accomplish this, it'd be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to make sure the fields are in your package. Go to Setup > Create > Packages > Your Package. If you don't see the fields under the "Components" tab, click "Add" to add them.

If you haven't already create a package, you'll have to do so first under Setup > Create > Packages.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Are there any concerns regarding the organizations licensing restricting the ability for them to create custom fields, or can everyone do this?

Comment: I believe all editions can add custom fields, but there are limits. This entry in the online help has the details: https://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/user_ed.jsp?section=help&target=limits.htm&loc=help&hash=CustomFieldLimitDetails